# How do I point a vanity URL to my homepage without the URL changing in the browser?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, alias

I'm trying to make a vanity URL, say example.com/saveWD, take someone to the homepage, example.com, but not actually redirect it - so they see example.com but the URL in their browser reads example.com/saveWD. Right now I have this in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^saveWD index.php
```

Is the best way to go about creating this? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you'd need to do something like this, but I've had to do much crazier things haha.

You can absolutely use .htaccess rules, which if you only need a few vanity URLs will be absolutely sufficient, or set up domain masking (which would probably be way over-complicated for this).

---

Shameless plug, I've also written a plugin that may work for what you need called [Content Mask](https://wordpress.org/plugins/content-mask/). You make a page/post and put a URL in the Content Mask URL field, and it will replace the content of that page/post with the content from the URL.

I wrote it because we needed to embed external landing pages and reputation software, such as `example-client.reputationsoftware.com` or `landingpagemaker.com/example-client/landing-page-1` onto `https://example.com/reviews` or `https://example.com/landing-page`.

I made a test using my plugin's homepage https://xhynk.com/content-mask/ and masking it on https://xhynk.com/content-mask/saveWD

You're more than welcome to give it a shot if you want, here's the source code of the current version so you can see nothing funky is going on: http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/content-mask/tags/1.2.0.2/content-mask.php